# using DeviceIoControl with HiD

Tags: c#, .net, hid

I am trying to write to a HiD driver in C# (V studio 2008) and decided to use the [DeviceIoContol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216%28VS.85%29.aspx) function to access the device. I'm however stumped as to what to substitute for the second parameter of this function, trawling the net hasn't yielded anything useful or explanatory so any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You're writing a kernel-mode _driver_ in C#? That's not possible, by definition.

Comment: Did you mean "write _to_ a HiD driver" ?

Comment: What's the question? The type of the second parameter (`uint`)? Or the values you need to pass (depends on the device)?

Comment: My apologies if I wasn't clear enough. I'm not trying to write a Kernel mode driver just a device driver for a USB HiD Device.

Comment: I've totally dumped the idea in favour of using filestream methods for accessing the device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there are no standard values to pass as the dwIoControlCode.  It depends on the device driver implementation, it determines what it will accept and what action it takes.  However, many control codes are documented in the MSDN library for drivers written by Microsoft.  Look through the MSDN Library index for keywords that start with IOCTL.  The first one that is HID device related is [`IOCTL_HID_ACTIVATE_DEVICE`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms790960.aspx)